# geolocation permission styling

Tags: html, css, geolocation, styles

Does anyone know of a way to style the bar asking permission to run geolocation?

```
<? nothing nothing nothing nothing ?>
<? nothing nothing nothing nothing ?>
<? nothing nothing nothing nothing ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you rephrase the question with more details / what you actually wish to accomplish (maybe a 'result' picture also)? You may else want to add a php tag?

Also, would this we on a computer, mobile device, or possibly both?

Short answer, if I understand your question to be if you can change the pop-up/message bar, I would say not, as it also seems to behave differently in different browser's, using it's own web bar/message.